# Getting the total impedance (and voltage from it)

Tags: passive-networks

Well considering below schematic, how can the voltage over the capicator be calculated?

I've tried first to solve it by mesh analysis (replacing the supplied voltage + resistor by thevenin's equivalent). However the calculation becomes quickly complex, with the meshes containg both integrals and differential equations.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3QvsN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now I tried to calculte this by using finding the equivalent (complex) impedance:
$$\mathbf{Z} = R_1 // \mathbf{Z_2} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{\mathbf{Z_2}}}$$
$$\mathbf{Z_2} = \mathbf{j} \omega L + \mathbf{Z_3}$$
$$\mathbf{Z_3} = R_2 // \frac{1}{\mathbf{j} \omega  L}$$
Now this could be written out, but I see no indication or "hint" to find \$\omega\$. Is this a good track to solve it?

How to solve this?

Comment: w=0, because your current source is constant and there is no switch.  So just consider L a short and C open.

Comment: @apalopohapa - Hmm makes sense.. But what "if" there was a switch (or in other words "the source has just been put on/nothing stored in the inductor/capacitor yet").

Comment: If you need to plot the voltages from power up then, to quote you "the calculation becomes quickly complex, with the meshes containg both integrals and differential equations"

Answer (score -3):

i cant react on the reaceactions above
but if there was a switch you woudnt calculate it with formulas like
Z=R1//Z2=11R1+1Z2
but you would calculate it in the s or z domain
nice thing to look to is the laplace transformation
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform

Comment: I don't recognize the formula in your answer as relating to the question. What does 11R1 and 1Z2 mean? Why would you calculate it in the Z domain? The link you provide gives not help to the uninitiated in laplace and is of no relevance to those who do know about laplace. This is a poor answer and you should consider putting some substance into it that makes sense before someone downvotes it.

Comment: i copied the formule out of the topic starters post

Comment: Not only does this lack information, but it contains capitalization and spelling errors that make it very difficult to read.